Install PacBio lima via conda fails
I'm trying to install lima from PacBio to demultiplex some sequencing data. I've tried in micromamba environments with python 2.7 and 3.10.13, but get the same error message.
Commands I've tried:
conda install -c bioconda lima
conda install bioconda::lima
conda install bioconda/label/cf201901::lima

Here's what I get:
$ conda install -c bioconda lima
pkgs/main/osx-64                                              No change
bioconda/noarch                                               No change
pkgs/main/noarch                                              No change
bioconda/osx-64                                               No change
pkgs/r/osx-64                                                 No change
pkgs/r/noarch                                                 No change
conda-forge/noarch                                  16.8MB @   1.1MB/s 15.5s
conda-forge/osx-64                                  34.0MB @   1.5MB/s 22.5s

Pinned packages:
  - python 2.7.*

error    libmamba Could not solve for environment specs
    The following package could not be installed
    └─ lima does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel).
critical libmamba Could not solve for environment specs
(py2) 

Does anyone have any ideas how to resolve? I'm on a MacBook if that makes any difference.

The official recommendation is to use micromamba or mamba to install this package , you can try that.
the package page
